# Can't get correct birth number in haskell function

Tags: haskell

I'm quite new to haskell, so I'd need some help, because I really don't understand why it's not working. I have a function as showed below, it should evaluate proper birth number. Calling function `birthNum` like this:

```
birthNum (Date 1992 9 14) Female
```

returns correct result (`925914`), but when I use it in function `birthNumber` I get strange results, for example something like this: 
`669205408` insead of, for example: `9259140000`.

```
data Date = Date Int Int Int -- Year, Month, Day
data Sex = Male | Female deriving Eq

birthNum (Date y m d) s = (y `mod` 100)*10000 + m*100 + d + sex s
    where sex s | (s == Male) = 0
                | otherwise = 5000

birthNumber (Date y m d) s = [birthNum (Date y m d) s *10000 + o | o <- [0..20], (birthNum (Date y m d) s + o) `mod` 11 == 0]
```

Comment: Applying it to `birthNumber` returns a list `[9259140000,9259140011]` with the first number in it which is the same as expected by you.

Comment: To be on the safer side you can use `Integer` for storing number of arbitrary precision. That may be the problem in your case.

Comment: I dont understand it, calling birthNumber (Date 1992 9 14) Female I get [669205408,669205419]

Comment: According to GHCi, `9259140000 :: Int32` yields exactly `669205408`, so it is indeed a problem of integer overflow. As @Sibi suggests, use `Integer` instead.

Comment: Basically, your numbers are too large for an `Int`: on 32-bit systems, the maximum number that `Int` can have is 2147483647. `Integer` instead has no bounds (except those imposed by the amount of memory you have).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `Date` type to this:

```
data Date = Date Integer Integer Integer
```

`Integer` can be used for storing numbers of arbitrary precision. Note that `Int` is machine specific. As @chi points out in your case you are being bitten by a 32-bit architecture. And moreover, it's a good practice to write type signature before the functions:

```
birthNum :: Date -> Sex -> Integer
birthNumber :: Date -> Sex -> [Integer]
```